# web-ext, profile and IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am developing a WebExtension that uses IndexedDB (porting [Skwares](https://github.com/EricViala/Skwares), only better).

I am also learning [web-ext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext). When running it with a profile, like so : `web-ext run --firefox-profile <profileName>` settings are indeed conserved from one lauch to the next, with the exception of the content of the database. Is there a reason for that ? A workaround ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe web-ext copies the specified profile to a temporary one, so everything from the existing profile transfers over, but not the reverse.  Once you close the browser, the temporary profile (along with anything saved in it) is deleted.

The workaround would be the actual solution, and that is to install the WebExtension into Firefox.